# Diff editor accessibility copy to clipboard

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say you want to diff these files in vscode

```bash
echo -e "Hi there" > foo
echo -e "Hi you" > bar
code --diff foo bar
```

When you open the diff, and then select the ["Open Accessible Diff Viewer"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility#_diff-editor-accessibility), it shows you a unified diff.
[image]

Is there a way to copy this unified diff shown ?
Or another way to get a unified diff using vscode ?

I know I can use `diff` directly, but my real goal is to be able to copy diff content within VScode, for example when reviewing Source Control diff, or when using some extensions to diff some random selections.
Then I could use this and paste it in markdown diff sections.